# "Cheatsheet" or checklist for Rails beginner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have recently begun the process of trying to learn Ruby/Rails and have been making my way through Agile Web Development with Rails (3rd Ed.). While the content of the book is great I really wish I had either a cheatsheet or a checklist of some sort that describes the steps one should take in order to create an application, and the proper syntax for doing so without taking up hundreds of pages. In essence I would love something that just gives the "broad strokes" of app development and some of the associated syntax while leaving the specifics to be learned by practice and attempting to create a "real" project.

I feel as if I understand the basic theory of how a Rails application works but need a crutch as I go through the development process for something other than a sample app you would find in a book. Are there any resources that would help in this situation? Or what would the best approach in my situation be?

Comment: https://github.com/cirosantilli/rails-cheat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).  This guide/checklist covers Installing Rails, creating a new Rails application, and connecting your application to a database, the general layout of a Rails application, the basic principles of MVC (Model, View Controller) and RESTful design and how to quickly generate the starting pieces of a Rails application.

You can also find a printable Rails on Rails cheat sheet [here](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/ruby-on-rails-cheat-sheet/).

Answer (score 3):

I would install the cheat gem and go from there.

```
$ sudo gem install cheat
```

then you can do

```
$ cheat cheat
```

to get help for the gem

```
$ cheat rails
```

for rails oriented cheat sheets

```
$ cheat anything-you-can-think-of---go-ahead-its-fun
```

etc. etc.

Answer (score 3):

[Rails Begineer Cheat Sheet](http://pragtob.github.io/rails-beginner-cheatsheet/index.html) by Tobias Pfeiffer is very handy and cover almost everything a rails beginner needs to know. Also check out [Rails 3 Cheat Sheets](http://blog.envylabs.com/post/29044764623/rails-3-cheat-sheets) by envy labs.

Other cheat sheets that might interest you:

http://owningrails.com/rails-4-diff-cheatsheet

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Ruby_on_Rails_Cheatsheet

http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/ruby-on-rails-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pdf ruby on rails cheat sheet you could also have a look at.

[Ruby on Rails Cheat Sheet](http://www.blainekendall.com/uploads/RubyOnRails-Cheatsheet-BlaineKendall.pdf)

Comment: I really like that format, but unfortunately it is from 2005 and Rails has changed significantly since then. Does anyone know of a more updated version of it or something close?

Answer (score 1):

[Added Byte](http://www.addedbytes.com)s has really good cheat sheets (In my opinion).

Here's the whole list offered:

http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/

Here's the Ruby on Rails:

http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/ruby-on-rails-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a "few" cheat sheets collected by me and Radarek's blog readers:
http://radarek.jogger.pl/2008/03/12/zestaw-ponad-40-sciagawek-dla-programistow-ruby-on-rails-i-n/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great one updated for Rails 3.

http://www.docstoc.com/docs/74836546/Rails-3-Cheat-Sheet

Comment: Thank you for you contribution!